# Use WCF channel in X++

Tags: wcf, microsoft-dynamics

I am developing a class in X++. In this class I need to send messages to third party application using a WCF custom channel written C#.

So my questions are:
1) Is it possible to create and use a WCF custom channel to send message inside a X++ method?

2) In WCF, channels are created using channel factories. They are declared something like  `IChannelFactory<IOutputChannel> fact;` Can this be done in X++ also?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality in Ax by writing your WCF service client in C# and then invoking the C# WCF client code from X++. You can have a wrapper that would perform both #1 and #2 in C#, and expose a simple non-generic interface for X++ consumption. This is also the [recommended way to consume an external WCF service from X++](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500185.aspx)

Note that in Ax2009 you had an option to create the service reference from inside Ax. For an easier upgrade from Ax2009 to Ax2012 it would probably be best to write the WCF client in C# and then add a reference to the client dll - that way you'll have less code to change on upgrade.

Also, some of the MSDN content on this topic is outdated. For example [this add service reference how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc636424.aspx) is plain wrong and does not apply to Ax2012 - you can verify this by seeing the menu items it mentions do not even exist in Ax2012.